# Create function for setting variable

Tags: macros

I have been using LaTeX for some years now, but I've only recently noticed its scripting features. Although, I find it hard to grasp many of the concepts. For example, I want to have a command `\docTitle{My Paper Title}` which I can call and then this will produce some variable that I can use in my `.sty` template file.

So in my `.tex` file, I will call `\docTitle{My Paper Title}` and then the `.sty` file should somehow call `\title{\docTitle}`. How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is exactly what the standard `\title` does, it just stores its argument in `\@title` however

```
\newcommand\mytitle{}
\newcommand\docTitle[1]{\renewcommand\mytitle{#1}}

..

\docTitle{My Paper Title}
```

will initialise an internal macro `\mytitle` to empty and then define it as `My Paper Title`